# How do I change the ElementUI Datepicker to be inline?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm currently using ElementUI throughout my vue.js app, and my problem is that I want to embed the datepicker into an ElementUI popover component. ElementUI doesn't currently support inline datepickers, and as I don't want to completely shift/start using another component library, I was wondering if anyone has found ways to remove the search bar/stuff around the datepicker (essentially need to have just the date picker always open and retain that functionality).

I tried to change the opacity of the datepicker to be 0 and keep the datepicker always focused, but it was always off center and I didn't have much luck with it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's probably outside the realm of possible customization allowed by the library outside of editing the ElementUI source code.  The [calendar](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/calendar.html) sounds more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: @yoduh Gotcha, so you're suggesting to use the calendar, but add a click handler to replicate the actions of the datepicker?